# Werkzung/Flask FileSystemCache - Do not delete

Tags: python, caching, werkzeug

I'm trying to use a Werkzung FileSystemCache. The constructor takes a 'threshold' and a 'timeout' argument, used for controlling the lifetime of objects, however I have one problem:

1) I don't want to set a 'timeout' or 'threshold' - I want the cache to be persistent.

*(had another which was a silly bug on my end so I edited it out)*

Any advice on solving either of these two issues?

Comment: I'd split these two questions up into two different threads.

Comment: Thanks - seems they were just the same issue, the timeout was just much shorted than I expeced. Will remove this

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to set a 'timeout' or 'threshold' - I want the cache to be persistent.

Persistent cache values will land in Werkzeug 0.11: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/pull/725

Comment: Thanks - I have implemented this for myself in the meantime.